# Views indicator inaccurate, shows one views on question with two close votes

Tags: bug, status-completed, views

Two close votes and only one person has viewed the question?

[image: screenshot]

How did this happen?

Comment: Freehand drop shadows? What were you thinking?

Comment: @balpha: I had to make up for the fact that I didn't know about freehand circles before..

Comment: I literally cracked up when I noticed the drop shadows!

Comment: +1 for freehand drop shadows, even though they were visibly added *after* the circles :D

Comment: @Pekka: How else would you add them?

Comment: @Billy by drawing the shadows first, and the circles on top of them.

Comment: @Earlz: Haha, me too. And I very rarely _actually_ laugh at stuff I see on the internet.

Comment: +1 cause I've noticed this, and also for the pluralization.

Comment: The link to the image is broken.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Likely due to caching. Close-vote counts are probably not cached, since that information is extremely important and prone to change rapidly. This, however, is not the case with views which could be cached and updated in longer periods.

Comment: Yet another reason why there should be a list somewhere of everything that is cached on the site :)

Answer (score 10):

Since other questions are being pointed here as dupes, I'll update this question.  From a technical standpoint, this was a separate issue than we have currently with caching.  Since this question, we greatly changed how ViewCount is stored/processed/updated.

Starting last night new questions are cached significantly less than old questions, the current rules are:

- A question *under* 10 minutes old will only cache its view count for **30 seconds**
- A question *over* 10 minutes old will cache for 5 minutes (we have a *lot* of view counts to cache...)

This should improve the UI since a new question is where this caching is more apparent/strange looking.

Keep in mind this doesn't solve the issue, it just improves it.  It would cause mass chaos to update the database on *every* view hit, so we collect a few before doing a batch update on each web server (30 on most sites, 300 on SO).  It's still possible (mainly at slower times of the day) to see some mis-match like the above screen shot, due to those close voters having views in a buffer that hasn't got enough views to flush yet for example, or just the 30 second caching itself.

Comment: Has this been changed by now? e.g. see [this](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105/view-counter-on-main-site-is-lagging).