# Views and upvotes mismatch on meta question

Tags: bug, views

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Views indicator inaccurate, shows one views on question with two close vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46974/views-indicator-inaccurate-shows-one-views-on-question-with-two-close-vote)

Pretty excited on catching this bit, probably a bug. Below are two screen-shots which show the views for a question and the up-votes count for question not matching properly.

[image]

I read [similar question in meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46974/views-indicator-inaccurate-shows-one-views-on-question-with-two-close-vote) during the posting of this question that this problem could be due to caching. Hence I again clicked on Unanswered tab and checked the questions list. Even there, the views was still not updated as shown in this image. Then I clicked on that question again and saw the views count was still 1. Not sure how often do these views count get refreshed?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, caching also happens on the server. So refreshing your browser won't help. Better luck next time :)

Comment: This isn't a new "bug", it's the same issue as from the Meta question you linked, and as @Benjol points out this is server-side caching of the views. View updates are fairly infrequent, something along the lines of every hour or half or so. You can see another example of this in the [picture for my Meta profile](http://i.imgur.com/3XBHj.png).

Comment: @Grace - As Benjol suggested, this is due to caching on server too. But please suggest what do I do? Shall I vote to close this as exact dupe or @Benjol can just add an answer and I can accept it to complete this question.

Comment: @Sachin I've already voted as a duplicate, myself.

Comment: @Grace - My question I asked only because it was kind of addition to the linked question. To see even after browser refresh, the counts mismatch. I am really not sure if this should be treated as duplicate. Please no offense meant, this is what I feel.

Comment: No offense taken. I understand your stance, but that is how server-side caching works, which is what Jonathan was referring to in his answer to the other question. Refreshing the browser wouldn't fix that one, either, because it's still the same issue. Fret not - closing doesn't remove the question, and it'll still be around for the next time someone comes with the same concern.

Comment: @Grace - Ok, thanks grace. Have voted to close the question too. :)