# Why I get -1 immediately after asking?

Tags: support, down-votes

Sometimes I get a -1 immediately after asking a question. I don't know why. Is this a bug?

I get this immediately when just 1 view is recorded that's me. No one saw my question and I have a -1!

For example I asked this question today and got -1 immediately:

[I cannot compile an Android app with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30565748/i-cannot-compile-an-android-app-with-qt)

Comment: Downvoters: this is not the usual whine that "someone downvoted my question". He's asking how he can have a downvote when (apparently) he is the only person to have ever even _seen_ his question - as the view count is 1.

Comment: The view counts take some time to update.

Comment: @S.L.Barth no rant, but using some common sense it should be obvious that there's no "automatic downvote" involved - actual person is downvoting, for his/her own reason. Might be just a frustrated troll who is upset with Stack Overflow hence downvoting everything as revenge.

Comment: Also: [Views and upvotes mismatch on meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77913/262755)

Comment: Also: [View count out of date on a Stack Overflow question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80615/262755)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently, someone didn't like your post. Maybe it was the lack of necessary information, the bad layout, etc.

Someone thought that your question was either (description from the down-vote button):

- Not useful;
- Not well-researched;
- Unclear.

Since someone else up-voted you, you shouldn't be too worried. In your case, adding the error message seems to be very necessary, since the post on itself wasn't that clear. You updated your question and possibly that was the effect the down-voter was after.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible that I get a -1 automatically?

Comment: Not unless someone flagged your question as spam. The view count isn't updated the same time as the votes which are real-time. If you hit `Refresh` you will see the updated vote count.

Comment: @Patrick not really, Even hitting refresh 10 times won't show the actual views since it's cached server side for several minutes - what we see is the actual views count up to [x] minutes ago, not sure what "x" is though.

Comment: @Sha that would support the general idea behind my comment even more. You can't rely on the view count.

Comment: True, but you said " If you hit Refresh you will see the updated vote count" and this is wrong. (that's what I was referring to)

Comment: @Sha you are right on that. My bad.