# An answer has more votes than views

Tags: support, views, vote-count

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Views and upvotes mismatch on meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77913/views-and-upvotes-mismatch-on-meta-question)
>   [Views indicator inaccurate, shows one views on question with two close vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46974/views-indicator-inaccurate-shows-one-views-on-question-with-two-close-vote)

I have noticed this several times that an answer has got more votes than the views of the question itself. How is it possible? If a user came and voted up an answer then why was it not incremented in the number of views too? If a post has 7 votes then views should always be >= to 7. Is this a bug or are views not updated as frequently as vote count?

After few minutes the view count does increase and it starts to make sense.

For example [this question at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5019189/399722) had 7 votes to an answer but only 3 view count. When I refreshed the browser 3 to 4 times then suddenly the view count increased to 22.

Comment: Same issue as at [Views and upvotes mismatch on meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77913/views-and-upvotes-mismatch-on-meta-question). It's a buffer and cache thing for views.

Comment: oh!! looks like i didn't used proper keyword to search that duplicate..

Answer (score 8):

This is because view counts are heavily buffered before writing and also heavily cached.

If the problem persists for more than 24-36 hours let us know, otherwise this is completely normal and has been discussed dozens of times already on meta.

Comment: I see this all the time on the newer, lower-traffic sites I frequent.  On those sites votes approximately equal views since there aren't many of us looking at the questions and we want to vote up new questions as soon as possible to encourage the asker (unless the question is truly bad, of course).  At any rate, why not set views = votes if votes > views when you render the page?  It's no more accurate, but it does remove a tiny niggle for those of us who notice.

Answer (score 5):

There is some caching that goes on with view counts.  As long as refreshing / waiting a little bit for stats to catch up fixes the issue, I would not worry about it.

Comment: Good advice... I am now worrying. ;-)