# View count out of date on a Stack Overflow question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, views

[This Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115434/what-is-generics-and-its-uses-and-application) at the time I looked at it, had comments from 3 different users, 2 close votes - and a view count of 1:

[image]

Obviously the view count shown is out of date. A minor issue, but I thought it worth reporting, as I haven't found any prior similar posts.

Comment: possible duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46974/views-indicator-inaccurate-shows-one-views-on-question-with-two-close-vote, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77913/views-and-upvotes-mismatch-on-meta-question

Answer (score 8):

This isn't actually related to the proposed duplicate, it's a separate (recent) caching mechanism.  Starting a few weeks ago, we cache the view count for 5 minutes at a time (this may vary later, but it's the same on SO as other sites, for now).

View Count is an *incredibly* expensive thing for SO in particular given it's traffic numbers, we have to keep several things in mind, it has to be:

- synced across all web servers hosting SO (6 right now)
- written to the database

  - indexed, meaning that update isn't free or very cheap overall
  - written often, but not insanely often, like every view

To do this in a reasonable way, a few things happen here that cache at different levels:

1. To keep things sane, we rack up some view counts before updating them in a batch
2. The batch is *per web server* in local cache, then when it fills, views are incremented in the database
3. After 5 minutes, the cache shared between servers expires and refreshes from the database

Now immediately you think "well that's way more than 5 minutes"...that's not the case for SO. That per-server buffer isn't that large (300 at the moment for SO, 30 for other sites), it flushes in under a minute...much faster at peak traffic times.

All this means the *effective* delay in view count is about 5 minutes - that's why you'll see some strange numbers on a brand new question.

In the example above, given the time in the screenshot, a refresh over the next minute should update the view count (now at 50), since the question was asked at off-peak hours and that's the maximum time for that per-server buffer to do it's work.

Comment: +1 for the technical background info. Just as a thought experiment in the quest for perfection: since out of date view counts are most noticeable with new posts, would it make sense to refresh the view counts on new posts (e.g. younger than 5-10 mins) more often (maybe by using a separate cache for these)? I am not a web expert, so feel free to point out if there is any obvious problem with this :-)

Comment: @Péter - That's not a bad idea at all, starting in the build going out tonight, new questions less than 10 minutes old will cache for 30 seconds instead of 5 min, once they're 10 min old, they'll cache for 5 minutes like all other questions.

Comment: @Nick: If you flush the buffer to the database every 5 minutes, how do you enforce the rule of "1 request per IP per 15 minutes counts as a view"? I mean after you've cleared the buffer after 5 minutes you don't have the raw request data any longer.

Comment: @Developer - that's a different, independent throttling mechanism :)

Comment: Nick, could you please share some more details? I'm trying to implement something similar and I could really use some input.

Comment: @Developer - you can use a simple expiring cache object that ties a user to the question, if it exists, don't increment

Comment: @Nick, that's an interesting idea, thank you. And that cache object expires at predetermined points like every :15, :30, :45 and :00 minutes?

Comment: @Developer - XX min from current for example

Comment: Btw, that counter url found in each page with some random value which is changed every 15-18 minutes, does it have something to do with this "throttling mechanism"? I've recently asked a question about it, can't have missed it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87092/dissecting-stack-overflow-views-counter

Comment: So I've tried this approach and it seems to be working fine. Thank you for your useful hint.