# How does Stack Exchange find the number of unique views of a page?

Tags: support, views

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does stackoverflow calculate the number of views in a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-does-stackoverflow-calculate-the-number-of-views-in-a-question)

[image: profile views]

[image: question views]

If it is using cookies, how will it manage the users who clear their cookies after each browser session?

Comment: Also check out the answer from Nick [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80615/view-count-out-of-date-on-an-so-question/80636#80636) which provides some additional information about the caching and technical workings of the page view count.