# Reason for difference between post view counts

Tags: bug, questions, views

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [View count out of date on a Stack Overflow question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80615/view-count-out-of-date-on-a-stack-overflow-question)

When I look on the individual user page at the number of views a particular post has, I see that (for example) the question [Difference between covariance and upcasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707619/difference-between-covariance-and-upcasting) has (at the time of writing) 690 views:

[image: User page post views]

But when we click through to the question, it records one fewer (689 at the time of writing):

[image: Post page post views]

I've had a look at a few other questions, but can't find any that display the same behaviour.

Comment: Someone disliked the question so much that they erased it from their memory. It's like a new kind of super-downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the difference is most likely that the two sets of data are cached, but the data on the user page was cached later (count = 690) than the data on the question page (count = 689).

(Or, perhaps, that only the data on the question page are cached, i.e., used "old" data, whereas the user page data are uncached.)