# How can a question have more votes than views?

Tags: support, bug

I just noticed this

[image]

How does that come?

---

The question was spam. Though I'm wondering how I could see these stats? A *caching issue* maybe?

Comment: More likely that Smoke Detector "views" don't count as individual views since spam flags can be cast through the API without viewing the page... maybe?

Comment: The dev answer on the duplicate [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/46974/284336) gives a 30 second cache on new questions. If that's still current, you could easily have caught it during that window since flags for spam can accumulate quickly. Plus, users can sort of cast two downvotes on spam. One is automatically applied with the flag and a second may be added by the flagger manually... meaning one view can result in two downvotes.